# How do i change the color of the Date cell, when there is an event in it?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I want to change the background color of the date cell, But my code is not changing the color of the cell. The background of the event is the one that is changing. This is my code.

```
eventRender: function (info) {
    if(info.event.title == "FULL") { // if title contains "FULL"
        $(info.el).css( {'background-color': 'red', 'border': '1px solid #14B9E2'} );
    }
},
```

How can i access the `.fc` of that event? because i need to change the color of its background.

Comment: You would need to locate the correct cell by getting the start date of the event and then finding the cell using its "data-date" attribute to create a suitable CSS selector. Have you looked at the HTML of the calendar? e.g. in month view, a day cell will have HTML something like this: `<td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sun fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2019-05-26"></td>` . So you can identify it by the .fc-day class (for all day cells) and also the specific data-date attribute containing the exact date.

Comment: so it should at least look like this `$('.fc-day[data-date:"2019-05-26"]').css( {'background-color': 'red', 'border': '1px solid #14B9E2'} )` ?

Comment: That's the general idea but you need to take a closer look at the syntax for [attribute selectors](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) . It uses `=` rather than `:`

Answer (score 0):

```
dayRender: function (info) {
    var currentDate = new moment(info.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    $('td [data-date="' + currentDate + '"]').addClass('ClassOfDayWithNewBackground');
}
```